# Git branch named release cannot be deleted and prevents creating branches prefixed with release/

Tags: git, bitbucket

I cannot create branches prefixed with release:

```
$ git checkout master && git pull
$ git checkout -b release/0.7.6
$ git push --set-upstream origin release/0.7.6
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: 
remote: Create pull request for release/0.7.6:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx/pull-requests/new?source=release/0.7.6&t=1
remote: 
To bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx.git
 * [new branch]      release/0.7.6 -> release/0.7.6
Branch 'release/0.7.6' set up to track remote branch 'release/0.7.6' from 'origin'.
error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/release/0.7.6': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/release/0.7.6': 'refs/remotes/origin/release' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/release/0.7.6'
```

When I look in the bitbucket interface, I can see the branch `release/0.7.6` there, 0 commits before and 0 commits ahead of master.

Writing `git fetch` produces additional errors:

```
$ git fetch
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/release/0.7.6': 'refs/remotes/origin/release' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/release/0.7.6'
From bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx
 ! [new branch]      release/0.7.6 -> origin/release/0.7.6  (unable to update local ref)
```

When I write `git checkout` and use tab completion, I indeed get the suggestion that `release` would be something I can check out, but again it fails when I try to do that:

```
$ git checkout release
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/release': 'refs/heads/release/0.7.6' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/release
```

I can see there is something called `release` and it is listed in red, but I cannot delete it:

```
$ git branch -a | grep remotes/origin/release
  remotes/origin/release
$ git branch -D origin/release
error: branch 'origin/release' not found.
$ git branch -D release
error: branch 'release' not found.
$ git branch -D remotes/origin/release
error: branch 'remotes/origin/release' not found.
```

It can be checked out if I first remove my created `release/0.7.6`

```
$ git checkout release
Branch 'release' set up to track remote branch 'release' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'release'
```

What have I managed to do, and how can I solve it?

**Update**
Our bitbucket branching model is traditional git flow:

[image]

The branch permissions have protected history and write on master, only allowed to merge with a PR.

I can't find any setting that would cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; Branches with the pattern `A/B` exist as a file named `B` in a folder named `A`. If you already have another branch named `A`, you will get an error similar to what you see.

> error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/release/0.7.6': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/release/0.7.6': 'refs/remotes/origin/release' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/release/0.7.6'

The error tells you that a branch named `release` already exists in your BitBucket repo. Under the hood this is stored in a file in `.git/refs/remotes/origin/release`. Now you are trying to push a branch named `release/0.7.6` which will create a file in `.git/refs/remotes/origin/release/0.7.6`. Since the file `release` already exists, git cannot create a folder named `release` to store the `0.7.6` file in.

To fix the problem, first double check that you can remove the `release` branch. If you are sure this is safe, then you can delete it with `git push origin :release`.

Comment: Awesome, explained the root of the problem and how to solve it. Everything works again, thank you so much!